# Share Outlook Calendar Without Showing Details?

Tags: outlook, calendar

Is there a way to share my outlook calendar with somebody outside of my organization without them seeing the details of my meetings?

I'd prefer to just black them out and do a Snipit but whatever works...

Something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pGP1.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.

But you may configure this on the Exchange server-side or in Outlook manually. Take a look at the following articles:

- [Share an Outlook calendar with other people](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-an-Outlook-calendar-with-other-people-353ed2c1-3ec5-449d-8c73-6931a0adab88)
- [Share your calendar in Outlook on the web](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-your-calendar-in-outlook-on-the-web-7ecef8ae-139c-40d9-bae2-a23977ee58d5)